# How to validate email in ASP.NET Web API 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Please provide me regular expression to validate email id like below in web api method:

```
// GET: users/sample%40email.com
[Route("users/{emailAddress:regex()}")] 
public IHttpActionResult GetUser(string emailAddress)
```

Here i need regular expression which will validate email like sample%40email.com and will work in :regex() of web api route attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below solution worked for me. Thanks for the help.

```
// GET: users/sample%40email.com    
[Route("users/{emailAddress:regex(\\[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})}")] 
public IHttpActionResult GetUser(string emailAddress)
```

Comment: Never try to validate emails using a complex regex. You never manage to get it right according to the rfc. Do minimal validation on the form `(.*)@(.*)\.(.*)`, and just verify that the email exists buy sending them an email.

Comment: Just to comment for anyone else looking into this. While this does the work, is technically not validation but routing. It will only route calls that match to that regex. Thus you will get a 404 if the string after users doesn't match the email address regex.

Answer (score 10):

What version of framework do you use? If this is framework 4.5 you apply Email attribute

```
 [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Not a valid email")]
```

RegEx will look like this

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[email]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$
```

Answer (score 4):

You have several options to validate the email address. You can use regex or [MailAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) Class.

**Regex**

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

**Usage**

```
bool isEmail = Regex.IsMatch(emailAddress, @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**Using MailAddress**

```
public bool IsValid(string emailAddress)
{
    try
    {
        MailAddress m = new MailAddress(emailaddress);

        return true;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to validate email before api action starts execution. so here Regex.IsMatch is not useful. But thanks for the regular expression.